# from an OOP perspective how bad it is to have objects that have fixed states?

Tags: python, oop

So I am a little confused about what I have been reading on Object Oriented Programming. I realized that while I was focusing on the rule of each object doing only one thing, I created a class that does not have a changing state.

Basically I am writing a program that does a lot of reading and writing on text files. I thought that none of the objects I have should be dealing with these operations and I should have a fileIO class that does these operations for them. However, I am a little worried that this might be the same thing as having a utility class.

Is having a class whose fields never change(or not even need to be initialized) same as a utility class? Is it a bad practice from OOP perspective? Does it make sense to have a fileIO object? If not should objects be allowed to read from and write to files?

```
class fileIO:
    __processFilePath = None
    __trackFilePath = None

    def __init__(self, iProcessFilePath, iTrackFilePath):

    def getProcesses(self):

    #checks if appString is in file
    def isAppRunning(self,appString):

    #reads all
    def getAllTrackedLines(self):

    #appends
    def addNewOnTracked(self,toBeAdded):

    #overwrites
    def overWriteTrackedLines(self,fullData):
```

in this particular instance I am actually initializing the fields in the init method. But for the purposes of my program I don't actually need to because there are only two files that I read and write from.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you are doing to the files, but if you are just doing straight processing of the files i.e. read->process->write->done, then the fact you don't change state suggests that you don't need objects at all. Just call the functions sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and Writing data from file can be wrapped in some class that handles the state of the data to ensure that the transaction completes. What I mean by this is that the resource needs to be de-allocated properly, preferably in the same transaction, no matter the outcome of the operation. If you consider the allocation and de-allocation of resources as state, then your class is not exactly stateless. In functional programming, a function handling resources will be considered impure as it is not stateless. The state is merely external.

Having a class with no state does not constitute a bad class. It is true that Utility classes are an anti-pattern, but if your class does one small thing, and it does it well, then it is not a problem. The problem comes in when you have a ton of related methods bunched into the class and the code begins to rot. That is what you want to avoid. A class that has a well defined purpose, and only does that thing, will resist rot.

Make sure you write lots of tests around your class as well, as this is key in long term maintainability.

Please let me know if there is anything that I can clarify.